# Firebase_admin pacjage problem with ServiceAccountCredential('service-account.json')

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-admin

I was working on making custom claims by using **fiebase_admin: 2.0** package but the vscode does not see the ServiceAccountCredential class as in the following screen shot

and here is my code

```
import 'package:firebase_admin/firebase_admin.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class _FirebaseAdminService {
  var app = FirebaseAdmin.instance.initializeApp(AppOptions(
    credential: ServiceAccountCredential('service-account.json'),
  ));

  customClaimsForAdmin(String uid) {
    app.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {'role': 'admin'});
    debugPrint('custom claim registered successfully as an admin');
  }

  readClaims(String uid) {
    app
        .auth()
        .getUser(uid)
        .then((value) => debugPrint(value.customClaims.toString()));
  }
}

// ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
_FirebaseAdminService firebaseAdminService = _FirebaseAdminService();
```

i tried to change the package version and try many alternative classes  but it did not work